# Joint PDF solving

Tags: probability, density-function

[image: The question is as shown]

The final answer for the problem says its 7/20. But i dont understand how the solution is real value. I tried to simplify it but got stuck at (3-2rooty-y)/2. 
Please help

Comment: The probability of course should be a real number. you might want to include your working so that we can point out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X,Y$ are both almost surely positive, then:   $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>\surd Y) {}&= \mathsf P(X^2>Y) \\ &= \int_0^1\int_0^{x^2} (x+y)~\mathsf dy~\mathsf d x \end{align}$$

From this you should immediately anticipate a *rational* result.

---

However, it looks like you tried directly: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>\surd Y) {}&= \int_0^1\int_{\surd y}^1 (x+y)~\mathsf dx~\mathsf d y \end{align}$$

This is *slightly* harder to do by hand, because *fractions*.   But if you persevere and take care, it does give the same result.